# Does the CONSTANT declaration stores the values in Block-RAM or in flipflops of an FPGA?

Tags: filter, vhdl, constants

For example, if I want to store my filter coefficients in n-Tap FIR filters using constants, will the `CONSTANT` declaration store my values in Block RAMs or registers using FPGA flipflops? Also can `SIGNAL` be used to store the coefficients without using RAM cells?

Comment: By default they will be transformed into logic equations that get baked into other circuitry and are stored implicitly in your target architecture's logic primitives. You can take steps to implement constant data as ROM implemented using distributed memory or block RAMs but that requires you to follow certain coding styles so that the synthesizer will infer a memory.

Answer (score 5):

The constants themselves aren't "stored" anywhere - their values are simply substituted into the VHL code where you use them.

Where they're stored depends on how you use them and how the code is optimized.

If you're multiplying a signal by a constant two, for example, no elements are used at all - the data bus will be simply connected in a way that effectively shifts the value left by one bit.

Or, they may end up as hard-wired inputs to other elements like multipliers in your case.

Either way, you should look into the synthesis results to thoroughly understand the generated RTL.

Answer (score 4):

> [...] will the `CONSTANT` declaration store my values in Block RAMs or registers using FPGA flipflops?

Whether constants are stored in memory blocks or registers, or if they are merged into the boolen equations depends on your implementation of an algorithm. Let's have a look on the following mathematical equation (not VHDL code):

```
y = c_1 * x_1 + c_2 * x_2 + c_3 * x_3 +... + c_N * x_N
```

`N` is the number of coefficients, `x_i` are the input values, and `c_i` are the constant coefficients.

You can implements this equation in VHDL / hardware by:

1. `N` parallel multipliers and an adder tree to sum up the products; all done combinational, within one clock cycle or even pipelined with a throughput of one result per clock cycle.
2. Or `N` sequentially executed multiply-accumlate steps; with one multiply-accumlate per clock cycle.

You can take even a combination of both.

In case 1, the synthesizer optimizes each multiplication with a constant:

- just wiring if the coefficient is a power of two,
- addition if the binary representation of the coefficient contains a small number of ones (5*x = x + 4*x),
- or multiplier hard macro with a constant value (VDD, GND) connected to one if its inputs.

Thus, in case 1 no memory or registers are required to store the constants.

In case 2, the synthesizer will map the multiply-accumulate step to a hardware multiplier plus an adder. This multiplier and adder will be re-used for all `N` steps, so that, the coefficients must be looked up in a memory. If you have a lot of coefficients, then memory blocks (Block-RAM) are used. The current iteration step `i` will make up the memory address. If you have only a small number of coefficients, then they can also be stored in distributed memory (LUT-RAM) or computed via boolean equations. But even in this case, the coefficients will **not** be mapped to flip-flops because their value do not change with time.

> Also can `SIGNAL` be used to store the coefficients without using RAM cells?

Yes, of course. With a proper synchronous description they will be mapped to flip-flops.

Comment: Nice answer. I think our answers say the same thing, but yours has more detail than mine. It's often helpful to have multiple answers explaining things differently.

Answer (score 1):

The used storage element:

- registers
- distributed RAM (LUTRAM)
- BlockRAM

...depends on your chosen VHDL description and size.

You should use a constant instead of a signal. Moreover it could be helpful to used synchronous read operations to infer registered outputs.

Look into the synthesis report to validate the intended description.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Paebbels' answer, it depends.  Though they can be implemented in distributed ROM (LUTROM) as well.  It depends on the synthesis tool.  For example, Xilinx's Vivado has in their synthesis guide ([UG901](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf)) describes how to infer RAM/ROM.

For your example of a FIR filter, you might have something like:

```
type coeff_array is array(natural range<>) of std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
constant coeffs : coeff_array(0 to N-1) := ( x"XXXX", x"XXXX", ..., x"XXXX" );
```

Now, whether this is a distributed ROM or RAM depends on the tool.  A quick test with Vivado shows this construct synthesizes to a sea of gates (just LUT logic).  However, it can be forced into a block RAM (aka block ROM) by:

```
signal coeffs : coeff_array(0 to N-1) := ( x"XXXX", x"XXXX", ..., x"XXXX" );
attribute ROM_STYLE : string;
attribute ROM_STYLE of coeffs : signal is "block";
```

The means to infer any specific type of structure (LUTs, LUTRAM, LUTROM, block ROM, block RAM) depends upon the tools in question.  Run the test through synthesis to see what you get.  And look at the synthesis guide for the synthesizer you are using to figure out how to get what you want.